# Problem on a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a unit vector $v= (a\       b\       c)^{T}$ be such that $Av=0$, 
where
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix} 
  5/6 & -1/3 & -1/6 \\
  -1/3& 1/3 & -1/3 \\
   -1/6& -1/3 & 5/6 \\
    \end{matrix}\right)$$
Then the value of $\sqrt6( |a|+ |b| + |c|)$ equals....$?$

Since the determinant of A is non zero, so the homogeneous system $Av=0$ should have only zero solution. So $v$ should be a zero vector. Then how can I find a unit vector satisfying this condition$?$

Comment: Are you sure the determinant is nonzero? To make the calculation easier, look at the matrix $$B = 6A = \left(\begin{matrix} 5 & -2 & -1 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 \\-1 & -2 & 5\end{matrix}\right)$$ which is made up of all whole numbers. Then $\det(A) = 0$ if and only if $\det(B) = 0$.

Comment: If $v$ satisfies $Av = 0$, then so does $2v$. Hence, the value of $\sqrt6 \left(|a|+|b|+|c|\right)$ cannot be uniquely determined, unless it is $0$, which would be the case if $A$ is nonsingular. Is $A$ nonsingular?

Comment: I solved the question. $A$ is singular matrix. ( First I thought it to be non singular due to some calculation mistakes). The answer I got is $4$. I don't know what do you mean @darij grinberg by "cannot be uniquely determined, unless it is 0".

Comment: @darijgrinberg it is a unit vector

Comment: Let me encourage you, Mathsaddict, to write up your solution, and post it as an answer.

Comment: I did some reformatting, better check that I didn't accidentally change the question.

Comment: Are you still here, Mathsaddict?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  sir, I'm not really comfortable with latex commands on stack exchange, since I use it on my smartphone. So writing equations, forming matrices would be really horrible. So it is better if someone else write solution to this problem.

Comment: Done. Any thoughts, Mathsaddict?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I thought, I would have to write all the steps, equations involved in finding the unit vector. You explained the answer without any calculation and it is still understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we have an answer....

The matrix $A$ is singular. The matrix $B=6A$ has integer entries (as noted in the comments), and so is easier to work with, and $Bv=0$ if and only if $Av=0$, so we'll work with $B$. By inspection (or, if you must, by the usual row reduction techniques), we find that $v=(1,2,1)$ is a solution. But we want a unit vector, so we calculate the norm of $v$, which is $\sqrt6$, and divide by it. Thus, the relevant vectors are $(a,b,c)=\pm(1,2,1)/\sqrt6$. It follows that $$\sqrt6(|a|+|b|+|c|)=\sqrt6(1+2+1)/\sqrt6=4$$ in agreement with what OP reports in the comments.